# I deleted ubuntu-desktop when removing abiword... Is it safe to auto remove?

Tags: lubuntu

After removing ubuntu-desktop when I was removing abiword and other default files on lubuntu 14.04, I am kinda unsure if it is safe to use apt-get autoremove.

Here are the list of files that are being deleted:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
brasero-cdrkit brasero-common ca-certificates-java default-jre
default-jre-headless dvd+rw-tools fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-gentium
fonts-sil-gentium-basic growisofs icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common
libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
libboost-date-time1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libbrasero-media3-1
libcdr-0.0-0 libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1 libcmis-0.4-4
libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libgconf2-4 libgmime-2.6-0
libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0
libgnomevfs2-common libhsqldb1.8.0-java libhyphen0 libidl-common libidl0
liblangtag-common liblangtag1 libmspub-0.0-0 libmythes-1.2-0 liborbit-2-0
liborbit2 liborcus-0.6-0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk
libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-writer libservlet3.0-java
libtotem-plparser18 libvisio-0.0-0 openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
python3-uno tzdata-java uno-libs3 ure xfonts-mathml

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 69 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 370 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] N 
Abort.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in here should totally break your system. From what is listed, you will be removing:

- Java (for browser plugin and Java programs)
- LibreOffice (the office programs suite)
- Brasero (for CD burning)

It's possible some of the libraries will impact functionality of other programs as well. It's better to only specifically remove what you know you don't need than do the `autoremove`.